# Need a query that will allow me add the value from column A with the value from column B

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Need a query that will allow me add a new Data of column A with the last data on column B, then store inside the same table.

To clarify, in a table I have columns named quantity_added and quantity_left.

When storing new data, I want to add the new value supply for column quantity_added with the last value on column quantity_left as the new value for column quantity left to be stored as pat of the new data.

E.g

```
Quantity_added = 2, quantity_left = 10,
```

**quantity_left  = Quantity_added + quantity_left**

**2 + 10 = 12**

The New value for

```
quantity_left = 12
```

Table example

```
      id  description    quantity_added      quantity_left     created  

      1    shoes             2                   10           21-4-2018  

      2    shoes             34                  44           22-4-2018

      3    shoes             6                   50           23-4-2018
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us some table structure here.

Comment: Also do you want a table level trigger or a php solution ?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to store derived data? This is generally not considered a great idea.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen a table sample as been added

Comment: @SudiptaMondal  is there no eloquent solution cos I want to be able to do this in my controller

Answer (score 0):

Try similar this

```
$data = ['Quantity_added' => 2]; // your initial data   
$data['quantity_left'] = $data['Quantity_added']; // assign Quantity_added value to quantity_left 
$model = EloquentModel::orderByDesc('primary_key')->first(['quantity_left']) 

if ($model) {
    // if has record ind db add last record quantity_left value in $data['quantity_left'] 
    $data['quantity_left'] = $model->quantity_left;
}

Model::create($data);
```

Comment: this is in querybuilder, can you help me with the eloquent equivalent. Thanks

Comment: This used Eloquent model, If you want i can add answer using DB;

Comment: Are You  using Eloquent model, and can send me Model name

Answer (score 0):

In my response I suppose the table was a id column, like this:

### Table_name

- Id,
- Quantity_added,
- Quantity_left

  $add_quantity= DB::table('Table_name')->select('Quantity_added')->where('id', '=',$id)->first();
  $add_quantity = $add_quantity->Quantity_added;
  DB::table('Table_name')->increment('quantity_left', $add_quantity, ['id' => $id]);

Whenever I have to do SQL queries in Laravel, I consult this page of the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries

Comment: still not adding up, undefined variable $id

Answer (score 0):

```
     public function update(){ 
     $table=new Table;
     $last_quantity_added=Table::select('quantity_added')->orderBy('quantity_added', 'desc')->first();
     $table->quantity_added=$last_quantity_added+$quantity_added_value;
     $table->quantity_left=$quantity_added_value;
     $table->description=$desc_value;
     $table->created=$current_date;
     $table->save();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, but its not an update, its a create method using store

Comment: you clearly specify it `the new value for column quantity left to be stored as pat of the new data.`where is you asking for update here????

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your contribution. To achieve the above goal, the following were the codes that worked for me

```
 //select the last value of quantity_left
    $old_quantity = Asset::latest()->first()->quantity_left;
    $new_quantity = $request->quantity_added;

 //add it up with the new quantity_added value
    $asset->quantity_left = collect([ $old_quantity,  $new_quantity ])->sum();
```

For more read, you can look this up https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sum

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET 
    `quantity_added` = NEW_VALUE, 
    `quantity_left` = `quantity_left` + NEW_VALUE
```